# how to managed form '#type' => 'text_format' toolbar

Tags: 8, forms, wysiwyg

I have a simple form:

```
$form['module']['name'] = array(
        '#type' => 'text_format',
        '#title' => t('Name'),
        '#description' => $this->t('Some notes'),
        '#required' => FALSE,
        '#default_value' => '',
        '#format' => 'full_html',
        '#allowed_formats' => array('full_html'),
    );
```

and it gives me: [image: How to remove certain toolbar?]

Which is good, but then, i want to manage the toolbar to remove certain buttons (e.g. only allow bold, italic, and strikethrough and remove remaining)

Can this be achieved from my custom module?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to <kbd>+Add new text format</kbd> over at `/admin/config/content/formats`

[image]

Then <kbd>Configure</kbd> your new text format and remove those icons by grabing them and dragging them from the active toolbar to the available buttons section

[image]

Lastly, instead of `full_html`, use your custom format for your custom module.